# Google Drive Push notifications limitations

Tags: notifications, limit, drive

I've created an application which receives push-notifications (watches) of changes made to the spreadsheet in Google Drive. Everything is working fine! But when I make another change (within 30 seconds or so) in the Google Drive spreadsheet, Google is not sending another notification to my application. After some minutes it works again, but in the meantime Google is not sending notifications.

Is there an limit on the amount of changes wihtin a specific time-range?

Any help / ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

@Niek Jansen I have tried these and what I have noticed is that for excel docs it takes upto 2 minutes to send a notification again when the anything changes. For word, its ~30s and for ppt its around 2-3 minutes

Comment: Thanks for the research! It seems you're right about the two minute interval between changes made to the Spreadsheet. Do you think or know there is a way to speed up this process?

Comment: @Niek Jansen: That's what I am finding out!! But I have worked with MS Office365 and they have clearly mentioned their time limits as 2 min for excel/ppt unlike google drive. So I am assuming we don't have but because its not written anywhere I am still in search for an answer..